# Cross-browser SVG Animation with filter (Chrome works, not Firefox/Safari)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg, filter, safari

I have a rather unusual svg animation made with the use of `<feImage>`& `<feComposite>` filters and the `<use>` tag to create a Porter-Duff Out (knockout) effect, which cuts a circular hole to the leaf shape layer on the bottom.

I got everything working nicely in Chrome but found out different behaviors in Firefox and Safari.

Firefox would not render the filtered elements at all and from my searches online, the reason appears to be Firefox does not support fragmented svg elements in the feImage tag. However, even when I tried to replace that with 1) a full link to an actual svg file, and 2) data-URI (which were the suggestions from many sources) and still, nothing shows up.

In Safari, the filtered svg element (leaf shape) becomes blurry when zoomed and the position of the knockout element (circular hole) is off. It seems that I can correct the positioning issue by changing the transform-origin coordinates. However, that would then mess up the original rendering from Chrome. I haven't found out much about the blurry issue.

Below is the svg code in its entirely and a link to codepen: https://codepen.io/lanlanonearth/pen/vYBJopM

Would really appreciate some expertise help!

```
<svg id="bf-icon__prey-predator"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 135.21 180.5">
<defs>
<title>Porter-Duff Composite: Out</title>
<path id="leaf" class="cls-31" d="M69,1.69,67.61,0,66.18,1.69c-.16.19-16.69,19.72-33,43.86C11.17,78.16,0,103.23,0,120.07c0,19.22,6.9,35,20,45.61,11.91,9.7,28.39,14.82,47.66,14.82s35.75-5.12,47.66-14.82c13-10.61,19.94-26.39,19.94-45.61C135.21,80.15,71.74,4.87,69,1.69ZM3.75,120.07a52.1,52.1,0,0,1,2.09-13.6l59.74,46.32v18.29L3.83,123.2C3.79,122.17,3.75,121.13,3.75,120.07Zm65.58,28.59V129l53.6-39.8a123.76,123.76,0,0,1,5.4,13.76Zm0-24.37V107.46l45.39-34.35c2.37,4.22,4.59,8.44,6.59,12.59Zm0-21.54V84.48l35.81-27.31c2.65,4.16,5.24,8.4,7.7,12.65Zm0-23V63.08l.15.2L96.1,43.57c2.33,3.38,4.68,6.87,7,10.44Zm0-21V40.05l15.34-12.4c2.94,4,6.08,8.28,9.28,12.84Zm0-23.49V7.93c2.9,3.56,7.57,9.4,13.09,16.72Zm-3.75.06L52.66,24.84c5.39-7.15,10-12.92,12.92-16.54Zm0,4.83v18L41.43,40.25c3.1-4.4,6.13-8.57,9-12.41Zm0,45.51v16.52L22.52,69.56c2.24-3.85,4.58-7.69,7-11.46Zm0,21.22v17.46L13.82,85.88c2.07-4.3,4.37-8.67,6.83-13Zm0,22.13V148L7,102.62A125.48,125.48,0,0,1,12.2,89.35Zm3.75,42.72V153.41l60.14-46.62a52.32,52.32,0,0,1,2,13.28c0,1.2,0,2.38-.08,3.54l-24.46,19Zm-30-128.37L65.58,62.8V80.91l-34.06-26C34.09,51,36.7,47.07,39.29,43.33ZM4.21,128.25l61.37,47.57v.9C37.43,176.12,8.17,163,4.21,128.25Zm65.12,48.47v-.27l39.89-30.92,21.72-16.84C126.78,163.21,97.46,176.22,69.33,176.72Z"/>
<circle id="porter-duff-out" class="cls-32" cx="67.61" cy="136.66" r="40.05"/>
    <filter id="pd-out"
            x="0" y="0">
       <feImage     xlink:href="#leaf"
                    result="source"/>
       <feImage     xlink:href="#porter-duff-out"
                    result="destination"/>
       <feComposite operator="out"
                    in="source"
                    in2="destination"/>
     </filter>
<style>
.cls-31 {
  fill: #010101;
}

.cls-32 {
  fill: #fff;
}
@keyframes up-and-down {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-65px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-65px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes wing-flap-left {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-9deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes wing-flap-right {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(9deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

#beatle, #porter-duff-out {
  animation-name: up-and-down;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#wing-left {
  animation-name: wing-flap-left;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#wing-right {
  animation-name: wing-flap-right;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#wing-left, #wing-right, #beatle, #porter-duff-out {
  transform-origin: 67.607px 136.662px;
}
</style>
</defs>
<title>bf-icon__prey-predator</title>
<use xlink:href="#leaf" filter="url(#pd-out)"></use>
<g id="beatle">
<path id="wing-left" d="M33,131.18a35.05,35.05,0,0,0,29.14,40.11L73.1,102A35.06,35.06,0,0,0,33,131.18Zm24.34,22.66A5.63,5.63,0,1,1,51.92,148,5.62,5.62,0,0,1,57.33,153.84Zm-3-19.2a7.72,7.72,0,1,1-7.42-8A7.71,7.71,0,0,1,54.28,134.64ZM63,117.81A5.63,5.63,0,1,1,57.63,112,5.63,5.63,0,0,1,63,117.81Z"/>
<path id="wing-right" d="M62.12,102l11,69.25a35.06,35.06,0,0,0-11-69.25ZM83.3,148a5.63,5.63,0,1,1-5.42,5.84A5.62,5.62,0,0,1,83.3,148Zm5-21.37a7.72,7.72,0,1,1-7.42,8A7.72,7.72,0,0,1,88.35,126.63ZM77.59,112a5.63,5.63,0,1,1-5.41,5.84A5.64,5.64,0,0,1,77.59,112Z"/>
</g>

</svg>
```

Additionally, here is the external svg file for the leaf element, which when put into code via my own repository (http://lanlanonearth.github.io/porter-duff/bf-icon__prey-predator--test-animated.svg), shows up in Chrome (blurry) and Safari (not blurry) not Firefox. Though the same code renders nothing in codepen (https://codepen.io/lanlanonearth/pen/QWLMeXv).

```
<feImage xlink:href="http://lanlanonearth.github.io/porter-duff/bf-icon-data__prey-predator--leaf.svg" result="source"/>
```

```
<rect id="test" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#pd-out)"/>
```

And here is the data-URI version encoded from Yoksel's SVG encoder (https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/). The data-URI leaf element shows up in codepen with Chrome (https://codepen.io/lanlanonearth/pen/LYPzZyx) and not Safari or Firefox.

```
<feImage xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath id='leaf' fill='%23000000' d='M69,1.69,67.61,0,66.18,1.69c-.16.19-16.69,19.72-33,43.86C11.17,78.16,0,103.23,0,120.07c0,19.22,6.9,35,20,45.61,11.91,9.7,28.39,14.82,47.66,14.82s35.75-5.12,47.66-14.82c13-10.61,19.94-26.39,19.94-45.61C135.21,80.15,71.74,4.87,69,1.69ZM3.75,120.07a52.1,52.1,0,0,1,2.09-13.6l59.74,46.32v18.29L3.83,123.2C3.79,122.17,3.75,121.13,3.75,120.07Zm65.58,28.59V129l53.6-39.8a123.76,123.76,0,0,1,5.4,13.76Zm0-24.37V107.46l45.39-34.35c2.37,4.22,4.59,8.44,6.59,12.59Zm0-21.54V84.48l35.81-27.31c2.65,4.16,5.24,8.4,7.7,12.65Zm0-23V63.08l.15.2L96.1,43.57c2.33,3.38,4.68,6.87,7,10.44Zm0-21V40.05l15.34-12.4c2.94,4,6.08,8.28,9.28,12.84Zm0-23.49V7.93c2.9,3.56,7.57,9.4,13.09,16.72Zm-3.75.06L52.66,24.84c5.39-7.15,10-12.92,12.92-16.54Zm0,4.83v18L41.43,40.25c3.1-4.4,6.13-8.57,9-12.41Zm0,45.51v16.52L22.52,69.56c2.24-3.85,4.58-7.69,7-11.46Zm0,21.22v17.46L13.82,85.88c2.07-4.3,4.37-8.67,6.83-13Zm0,22.13V148L7,102.62A125.48,125.48,0,0,1,12.2,89.35Zm3.75,42.72V153.41l60.14-46.62a52.32,52.32,0,0,1,2,13.28c0,1.2,0,2.38-.08,3.54l-24.46,19Zm-30-128.37L65.58,62.8V80.91l-34.06-26C34.09,51,36.7,47.07,39.29,43.33ZM4.21,128.25l61.37,47.57v.9C37.43,176.12,8.17,163,4.21,128.25Zm65.12,48.47v-.27l39.89-30.92,21.72-16.84C126.78,163.21,97.46,176.22,69.33,176.72Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"
```

Comment: Getting rid of the filter makes it work in Firefox ... cannot test in Safari: https://codepen.io/elliz/pen/mdbBJaW

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you. I've edited to add more information on the external file version and the data-URI versions.

Comment: Hi Ruskin, yes I know. I want to try to use filter as that allows for the porter-duff (knockout) effect which can not be achieved otherwise. In other words, I want the moving circle to "cut" into the leaf shape so that it renders transparently rather than with a solid color.

Comment: Hi Robert, I gave width/height to both the svg element as well as the feImage element along with x and y attributes. Still, nothing in Firefox while Chrome implemented these changes.

Comment: Hi Robert, I just read your message again and realized that it's the referenced SVG image that you are talking about. I added width/height and the leaf finally showed up! Thank you for your insight helping me solve this mystery. I can accept your answer if you post it. I'm still sad that Firefox doesn't support fragments in svg as that would disable the animation part of it (I would have to resort back to the un-transparent way of doing it now).

Comment: You can always put the animation in the data-URI too.

Comment: Oh you mean having the referenced svg be animated within its own file?  Seems a little complicated but doable. I will have to try that. Thank you for your additional thought!

Comment: @lanlanonearth no worries ... you want the circle to be transparent to the background. You could probably get the same effect animating the circle as a `mask` on the leaf ... or even doing a 'line drawing' animation as a mask to simulate the eaten track of the bug. Enjoy

Comment: @Ruskin Thank you. I did thought about `mask`. How would you go about using it though? It seems that I need to move the entire mask to make the cut-out circle move and that makes the entire svg drawing area larger? Is there a smarter way in using `mask` or `clip-path` for my purpose?

Comment: @lanlanonearth I've started on the codepen above ... needs a lot of work e.g. at top of path mask rotates off to side for downward journey. May hack at it more in day or two: split each wing into symbol and animate separately, move entire beetle into symbol, so beetle wrapper and mask can have same animation ...

Comment: @Ruskin Thank you. For now I'm resorting to no mask/filter and just change the background color for the simplicity of it. But I am very interested in solving this problem with what's available in CSS. Thank you for tackling it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current releases of Firefox will display the SVG in the question.

Prior to version 123, Firefox required that the image referenced by the feImage element not only be complete i.e. not a fragment but also that that [image had width and height attributes that were not percentages](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1097856). The non-percentage restriction has now been fixed.